# Azure DevOps SetUp - Mulitple Project / WebJobs under Single Solution

Tags: azure-devops

We have about multiple Projects in a single Solution.

1. 2 projects needs to be deployed as Azure Web App
2. 10 projects are web jobs which needs be deployed to one of the Azure web app

Can someone guide me on how to setup the deployment pipeline for Continuous Integration.

Answer (score 0):

This is one option:

Setup build pipeline so that build will produce ready to install packages. An easy way to achieve this is to use Build solution Task and add following parameters into MSBuild arguments:
*/p:TransformConfigFiles=true /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:OutDir="$(build.stagingDirectory)"*
(+ of course you need publish symbols path and publish artifact task which are created by default)

Now when you build your solution you should have ready to install packages (zip files).

Next we need to setup deployment pipeline. Here you should use Azure App Service Deploy task. All the other parameters except package or folder should be easy to setup if you have linked Azure subscription into Azure DevOps.In package or folder you can put: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/(name of the zip package you want to deploy).zip.

Web jobs don't differ from apps much, so you should be able to setup their pipelines also with above guide.

For more information about web job deployment check this Microsoft example:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2016/05/18/deploying-and-schedule-azure-webjobs-from-vsts-to-azure-web-app-with-bonus-cron-scheduling/

Comment: Will try this and get back if any issues.